# How to drag an image and drop it at desired location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make an interface in which user can select and drag an image and drop it over at a desired position over another image.

I started with the following code. I am able to drag and drop, but the image gets dropped at top left corner automatically. I want to drop image at a desired position (for eg. in middle somewhere or bottom right etc...).  How can I do that ?

Code I started with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:900px;height:900px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you google this at all?

Comment: add a `console.log(ev);` to the drop function, this should help.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** try this:

```js
   

$('#drag1').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
});

    $( "#div1" ).droppable({
      tolerance: 'fit'
    });
```

```css
 #div1 {width:300px;height:300px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>droppable demo</title>
 
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    
        <div id="div1">Drop here</div>
        <img id="drag1" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_300,h_200,c_crop/sample.jpg"/>
         
     
         
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: i had tried your codes...they worked but the only prob is that dropped image is not constrained in the box, i need to fix that...Thanks! n btw i did not down vote.

Comment: can we accomplish the same without jQuery ?

Comment: it will be in box only.just inspect the div you will see.and why using javascript when you can write a small and easy code in jquery because you are already using it.

Comment: i tried your code in other computer and it worked in it but in my computer it is not working...therefore to would probs i was thinking of going with javascript. Thanks!

Comment: are you connected to internet.if not then you will have problem.I'll suggest download these jquery files and save them in your project.

Comment: YES I M CONNECTED TO INTERNET, BUT THEN ALSO I'LL TRY DOWNLOADING IT. THANKS!

Comment: This code actually works really well! One small thing though: on my browser (Chromium 56) it doesn't like the `src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"` part I had to write `https://` in the urls.